# STATUS:INVALID_ARGUMENT and ERROR: The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects

Tags: google-streetview-publish

In google street view while uploading the metadata of the photo in step 3 I am getting error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
    "message": "The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects.", 
    "code": 400, 
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help", 
        "links": [
          {
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/3624944027/apiui/credential", 
            "description": "Google developer console API key"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty self explanatory ...

Answer (score 14):

This means the API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects. Try to use an API Key that is from the same project as your credentials. You can even get rid of the API key, as the credentials alone should do the trick.